# Regex split pattern multiple lines

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to read some log data from txt file and split it accordingly.
My example file would look something like this:

```
11:03:04.234 DEBUG event occurred  
11:03:05.345 INFO another event occurred  
11:03:06.222 ERROR notice that this event
             occupies multiple lines
             as errors can be from multiple sources
             and I have no control over this
11:04:07.222 INFO fourth event has happened
```

I decided t use `StreamReader` as looks like it is the most efficient way. I read all of the contents of a file using `ReadToEnd()` method of `StreamReader` and receive one big string. Then, I try to use Regex to split the string. The Regex pattern I was able to come up with so far looks the following way:
`([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9].[0-9][0-9][0-9].*)`.
It works perfectly fine until, of course, the Regex parses the multiple line event.
I use [this tool](http://www.beansoftware.com/Test-Net-Regular-Expressions/Split-String.aspx) to test my patterns.

Comment: Try `(?m)^(?!\A)(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})`

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: How about you read a line, check for the time stamp, if it's there, parse the INFO/DEBUG/ERROR part, and capture the text, creating a new LogResd entry. If there's no time stamp at the start of a line, throw away the leading whitespace and concatenate the text to the last created entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Split(s, @"(?m)^(?!\A)(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%3F!%5CA%29%28%3F%3D%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B3%7D%29&i=11%3A03%3A04.234%20DEBUG%20event%20occurred%20%20%0D%0A11%3A03%3A05.345%20INFO%20another%20event%20occurred%20%20%0D%0A11%3A03%3A06.222%20ERROR%20notice%20that%20this%20event%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20occupies%20multiple%20lines%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20as%20errors%20can%20be%20from%20multiple%20sources%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20and%20I%20have%20no%20control%20over%20this%0D%0A11%3A04%3A07.222%20INFO%20fourth%20event%20has%20happened)

**Details**

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `(?!\A)` - but not the start of string
- `(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})` - that is followed with 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `:`, 2 digits, `.` and 3 digits.

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})(?:[\s\S](?!\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}))+
```

It starts by a looking ahead for: 2 digits, a colon, 2 digits, a colon, 2 digits, a dot and 3 digits.

Then it starts a non capturing Group, which matches any char (including Newline), the uses a negative look ahead for the same pattern as above. This Group is repeated one or more times.

Basically it matches a line that starts with a time and continues until it reaches a new time value (or end).

The MatchCollection will contain all matches.

How to use:

```
string text = "11:03:04.234 DEBUG event occurred\r\n11:03:05.345 INFO another event occurred\r\n11:03:06.222 ERROR notice that this event\r\noccupies multiple lines\r\nas errors can be from multiple sources\r\nand I have no control over this\r\n11:04:07.222 INFO fourth event has happened";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})(?:[\s\S](?!\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}))*");
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```